# "0x80020003 - Member not found" when passing a variable value to style nodes

Tags: dom, autohotkey

In the below code, if I specify the property value like `doc.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.fontweight`, it works but if I pass a variable, it throws the error. Why is it?

```
html =
(Ltrim
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    </html>
)

doc := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile") 
doc.write(html)
ChangeCSSRules(doc, "fontweight", "normal")
msgbox % doc.documentElement.innerHTML

ChangeCSSRules(doc, property, value) {
    doc.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style[property] := value    ; this causes "Error:  0x80020003 - Member not found."
    ; doc.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.fontweight := "normal"  ; this works            
}
```

---

It seems that using [] causes that error.

```
html =
(Ltrim
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    </html>
)

doc := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile") 
doc.write(html)

doc.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style["fontweight"] := "normal" ; this causes "Error:  0x80020003 - Member not found."
; doc.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.fontweight := "normal"  ; this works            
msgbox % doc.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, so that people know the problem has been resolved (and the solution will be found by future readers). The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has details on answering your own questions - you can even accept it as the proper answer after a period of time passes. (You don't earn reputation for doing so, but it is an indicator that the solution works properly.) Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite No, that's not a solution. The updated info narrows down the cause of the issue. Don't you see the problem? Obviously the DOM object is not accepting a key as an expression to be passed, which appears unusual to me. (I rephrased the post)

Comment: Ah, got it. I misread "it seems that using [] causes the error" and "; this works" as meaning you'd solved the problem. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

As i know it, it's because some properties of COM objects can accept parameters

That is a

> Known limitation:
>
> Currently x.y[z]() is treated as x["y", z](), which is not supported.
>   As a workaround, (x.y)[z]() evaluates x.y first, then uses the result
>   as the target of the method call. Note that x.y[z].() does not have
>   this limitation since it is evaluated the same as (x.y[z]).().

try it like this

```
test:="fontweight"
(doc.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style)[test] := "normal"
```

Hope it helps

best.

BlackHolyman